# Replacing Linq where statement with repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have  implemented the repository pattern in my WPF application like this :

```
 public interface ICrud<T> where  T : class 
        {
            IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
            Task<IEnumerable<T>> AsyncGetAll(); 
            void AddNew(params T[] items);
            void Delete(params T[] items);
            void Update(params T[] items);
            void SaveOrUpdate(params T[] items);
        }

     public class Crud<T> : ICrud<T> where T : class 
        {

            public void AddNew(params T[] items)
            {
                using (var context = new DataEntities())
                {
                    foreach (T item in items)
                    {
                        context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            public void Delete(params T[] items)
            {
                using (var context = new DataEntities())
                {
                    foreach (T item in items)
                    {
                        context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            public void Update(params T[] items)
            {
                using (var context = new DataEntities())
                {
                    foreach (T item in items)
                    {
                        context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges ();
                }
            }


            public  void SaveOrUpdate(params T[] items)
            {
                using (var context = new DataEntities())
                {
                    foreach (T item in items)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                             context.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                             context.SaveChanges();
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

            public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
            {
                using (var context = new DataEntities())
                {
                    DbSet<T> dbSet = context.Set<T>(); 
                    return dbSet.AsEnumerable().ToList();
                }
            }


            public Task<IEnumerable<T>> AsyncGetAll()
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {

                        var context = new DataEntities();
                        DbSet<T> dbSet = context.Set<T>();
                        return dbSet.AsEnumerable();

                });
            }
        }
```

I need to add to this implementation , a method which replaces a long `linq where statement` , I explain :

**Replace**

```
_DataContext.AddRange( (await SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<Student>>().AsyncGetAll()).Where(x => x.Name == "toto" && x.Age < 30 && .....).ToList() );
```

**By For Example**

```
_DataContext.AddRange(await SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICrud<Student>>().Fetch(ListOfConditions));
```

I need to know how can I do this? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following

```
    public IEnumerable<T> Search(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
      using(var context = new DataEntities())
      {
              return null != predicate
                    ? context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).AsEnumerable()
                    : context.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
      }
    }
```

You can call the method by using code such as

```
 Crud.Search(e => e.Id == 1);
```

where the class Crud implements the interface.